# tomcat7 redhat could not start up

Tags: java, tomcat7, redhat

I hava installed on RedHatEnterpriseLinux java1.7 and apache tomcat 7, starting tomcat on port 8080 and checking through

```
netstat -nap | grep 8080
```

and getting

```
tcp  0  0 :::8080  :::*  LISTEN      29178/java
```

but when i try to open tomcat home page from browser, browser is loading and loading and nothing appears. and when I try to stop tomcat server, I am getting

```
java.net.ConnectionException: Connection Refused error.
```

How can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

The Tomcat server may have bound to port 8080, but was unable to complete startup for some reason, and so not is not servicing requests yet.  Check the tomcat logs for errors, and make sure that the server has started successfully.   Successful startup of tomcat is usually indicated by the log statement "Server startup in XXXX ms" in catalina.out.

Comment: No error in tomcat logs, also no message that indicates server has start up in xxxx ms.

Comment: Sounds like startup isn't completing, although I don't have enough insight into your system to tell why.  I recommend reviewing all the tomcat logs in $CATALINA_HOME/logs for errors.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be in iptables. Try to open port 8080:

```
# lokkit --port=8080:tcp
```